# set encoding in XML Declaration

Tags: javascript, xml

I have one var `newMenuRoot = parseXML(SvgString,contextMenu)`, In this contextMenu (by default variable for svg) is Document type and which value is like 
some child nodes inside this node so I want to add encoding="utf-8" to this xml by javascript so that my svg supprot UTF-8 characters .

It should be like that  for default contextMenu

provide me solutions

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to provide a bit more information than that if anyone is going to help you.  Can you provide an example of the XML you're passing into parseXML() (e.g. the value of SvgString or contextMenu) and whether or not that's something you can control directly (e.g. is SvgString or contextMenu something you've written or is it some third party plugin or something).

I'd guess, from the small amount of information you've got there, that you'll just want to do a string replace or a RegEx replacement on the value of SvgString or contextMenu to replace whatever the current encoding is for the encoding you're after, but I don't think that will affect the ability of your SVG to handle additional characters etc.